# is delete this + memmove(this,new A(),sizeof(A)) safe and is it a bad idea?

Tags: c++, memory-management, coding-style

I searched some post about delete this in c++,and know that delete this is usually a bad idea,because delete this usually means poor management : the number of new and delete is not match, also it may have some pointers outside the class still point to this.

But the post I searched mostly about just deleting the original object, doesn't discuss the case of replacing the original object with new object.

sometimes I want to recreate the object,because I want the object to go back to initial state, by "realloc" the object using delete this+memmove(this,new A(),sizeof(A)) like this:

```
class A{
public:
    int value;
    void test(){
        delete this;
        memmove(this,new A(),sizeof(A));
    }
};
```

is it safe? or is there any undefined behaviour?

also if even it works,is it a bad coding style?

Comment: Hint: What does `this` point to after you execute `delete this;`? And what happens to the memory allocated by `new A()`?

Comment: `A a; a.test();` um... yeah. In order: it isn't safe, it invokes UB (not just the case I showed).

Comment: @amuse So far you have asked 41 questions on SO, and have received at least one answer for 37 of them, yet you haven't marked a single one as accepted. If an answer best helps solve your problem you can mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark next it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is heavily in UndefinedBehaviour-land. `delete this` does more than call the destructor—it deallocates the memory as well. The `memmove` thus copies into unallocated memory.

Furthermore, it has a memory leak, since the pointer returned from `new A()` is immediately forgotten.

I believe you intended to do this:

```
void test()
{
  this->~A();
  new (this) A();
}
```

This calls the destructor on `this`, and then the default constructor in the space pointed to by `this`.

The real questions is why do that, though. It's rather intricate low-level management. In my opinion, it would be better to give a proper assignment operator to the class and do this:

```
void test()
{
  *this = A();
}
```

Remember, the easier it is to understand what code does, the better the code generally is.

Answer (score 0):

delete this deallocate the memory. So the memmove writes in a dangling pointer which is undefined behavior.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but did you try move constructors introduced in c++11?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `delete this` - the self-destruction mechanisms used in some reference counting implementations work this way **BUT** you may not refer to `this` ever again at all because the results are undefined.

If you want to restore the same object to an initial state then can't you provide private `cleanup()` and `init()` methods that do the work?